# Help Identifying Photographic Paper

Tags: darkroom, paper, equipment-identification

Recently, I visited a relative, and he showed me a curiosity in his darkroom: A box of very old—and I think, odd—photographic paper he got with a variety of other papers on the internet.

It came in a box of 500 sheets, made by Gevaert, but since a good part of the label is missing, I was not able to identify this paper. Research for papers made by Gevaert showed up nothing like it. The reason why I'm interested in knowing more about it, is it's age, and it's strange properties.

**Description**

Considering the style of packaging/label, I'd guess it has been produced in the 60s or early 70s. It contains five stacks of 100 sheets each, sealed in black plastic bags (only one has been opened). Size is 20 × 30 cm, about 85 g/m² (calculated). One corner of each sheet is cut off, presumably to prevent mishandling in the dark.

The paper itself is smooth, but not coated. The (unexposed) senistive side has a slight yellow tint to it, and appears a bit glossy. The back is white, no sign of yellowing from age.

Now the interesting part:

It is *very* insensitive! As it turned out, this paper requires exposure to daylight for 0.5 to 5 seconds to get a decent contact print! While exposing, the yellow tint intensifies more and more. After development, the unexposed parts remain yellow. The colour can't be removed by extensive washing. The gradation seems to be rather hard. Otherwise, it develops just fine, no fogging, no stains or whatever.

**Question(s)**

Does anyone have any information about this kind of paper? Is the (dis)colouration and lack of sensitivity just a matter of age/degradation of the emulsion? Or is this some sort of special purpose paper, e.g. for text/microfiche reproduction, or wet copy process from the days before xerox photocopiers? I've made prints on decade-old paper before, but never came across anything like this.

Thanks in advance for help solving this little mystery!

Comment: if it is that old, it could be well past its use-by date (any such marking on the box?) in which case the characteristics you report may be the paper going out of specs with age.

Comment: Sounds a bit like Diazo/Blueprint paper, which would be developed to a blue image with ammonia fumes. How did you develop it?

Comment: I found no date on the box, the expiration date must have been on the part of the label that's missing.
Diazo paper is an interesting thought. I developed it with "Ilford Multigrade" (diluted 1:9) for 2 minutes, followed by an acidic stopp bath, and "Ilford Rapid Fixer". Rinsed in water for about 20 minutes (tried to wash out the colour).

Comment: Could be diffusion transfer paper?

Comment: As has been pointed out, low sensitivity emulsions, both film and paper, were typically used for reproducing technical drawings, to avoid midrange tones.